# Magento - eMail variables

Tags: php, magento

I want to customize my order confirmation and I can see that I can use if statements in my template and otherwise I can customize the `sendNewOrderEmail()` function to select two different templates based on some information.

However I am wondering because I use certain extensions to offer the customer a delivery date and a timeslot. Currently I use the placeholder `{{layout handle="deliverydate_email_information" order=$order}}` to display the delivery date. This one looks like this in the order confirmation:

```
Thursday, 28. July, 8pm - 10pm
```

But I want to have these kind of information in three placeholders like:

```
{deliverydate_weekday}
{deliverydate_date}
{deliverydate_time}
```

Does anybody knows how I can enhance my Magento system in a way that this is possible? I assume I can do it with implementing an own `layout handle="deliverydate_email_information"` but how do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the {deliverydate_weekday}
{deliverydate_date}
{deliverydate_time}

You need to define the variables in sendNewOrderEmail() like shown below (Define in your custom module where you are sending the email or extend the class. Do not edit code file):

```
    //get the value of $weekday, $deliverydate and $time from your extension 
$vars = Array('deliverydate_weekday' => $weekday,
                  'deliverydate_date' => $deliverydate,
                  'deliverydate_time' => $time);

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)
->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars, $storeId);
```

You can use the variables in template files as :

```
{deliverydate_weekday} {deliverydate_date} {deliverydate_time}
```

You can write use if directive like this :

```
    {{if order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
         //some code
    {{else}}
         //some code
    {{/if}}
```

For more info you can check these :
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5919/send-custom-mail-with-variable-via-script

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/

http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/transactional-emails-variable-magento/